# Flutter Wrap Widget does not expand itself

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a calendar and I'm using Wrap widget to display days inside calendar. But I faced a problem. Wrap widget does not expand itself to every side that's why overflow happens. This is my code:

```
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.40,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(46.0),
        color: Color(0xFFD6D6D6),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.16),
            offset: Offset(0, 10),
            blurRadius: 20.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 8.0),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                '${getMonthName(initialDate.month)}',
                style: GoogleFonts.baloo(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 50.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 8.0),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Wrap(
                  alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  spacing: 2.0,
                  children: dayList == null
                      ? SizedBox()
                      : dayList.map((e) {
                          return DaysContainer(
                            number: e,
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**When I remove upper Row in Wrap, this time widget only goes to vertical even though I define Axis.horizontal.**

DaysContainer class:

```
class DaysContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const DaysContainer({Key key, this.number, this.isAvailable})
      : super(key: key);

  final String number;
  final bool isAvailable;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          number,
          style: GoogleFonts.baloo(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            color: Color(0xFFBFBFBF),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the result in Flutter Web:

[image: Calendar days in row]

Expected result:

[image: Expected calendar wrap]

**Can anyone help me to figure out what is the problem in Wrap widget?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change to:

```
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5,
        child: Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          spacing: 2.0,
          children: dayList == null
              ? SizedBox()
              : dayList.map((e) {


...


class DaysContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const DaysContainer({Key key, this.number, this.isAvailable})
      : super(key: key);

  final String number;
  final bool isAvailable;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
                        width: 20,
                        height: 20,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          number,
          style: GoogleFonts.baloo(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            color: Color(0xFFBFBFBF),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please change your code with the following changes:

- Removed `Row` widget outside `Wrap`
- Defined your width of `DaysContainer`. Currently, the width of `Container` in `DaysContainer` has full width of parent widget. That is the reason why your time widget goes to vertical even though you define Axis.horizontal in `Wrap` widget.

By the way, you can add the properties `runSpacing` and `spacing` to your `Wrap` widget to give more space between your items in horizontal and vertical instead of using padding.